# Animate Jquery addClass on hover

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery so unsure how i would go about editing the code below to create a fade in when the class element is hovered over.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--     

$(function() {
$('div.work-item').hover(function() {

}).hover(function() {  
$(this).addClass("hover");  
}, function(){  
$(this).removeClass("hover"); 
});  

});
//--><!]]>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel sad when I see the CDATA Mangled Comments Hack in the wild. It is a horror I never intended anyone to actually use.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're fading in some other element when the first is hovered over.  Note that `hover` takes two arguments: a function when the item is hovered over and another when the mouse moves out of the element.  Since fadeIn/Out can take some time you might also want to look at the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to reduce inadvertent displays when simply mousing over the element and not actually intending to invoke the functionality.

```
$(function() { 
    $('div.work-item').hover(function() { 
        $('.selector-for-fadein-item').fadeIn('fast');    
    }, function(){   
        $('.selector-for-fadein-item').fadeOut('fast');     
    });
});
```